# how to remove access vagrant machine via vagrant ssh?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

It should be a simple question.

I had a vagrant box there, where I can start `vagrant ssh` to access it without password.

And how can I remotely execute ssh command to get some result like below, which can be used in jenkins CI server to check something.

```
$ vagrant ssh 'who -a'
```

My environment

- Vagrant 0.8.7
- Ubuntu 11.04 (host)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work; for more information check out `man vagrant`, `man ssh` and `man who`.

```
vagrant ssh -c "who -a"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following to see the ssh config behind the `vagrant ssh` command:

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

**Note:** This will only work once you did `vagrant up`.

Then use the ip, port, key, etc. in your own ssh command:

```
ssh -i /path/to/vagrant/keyfile vagrant@ip:port who -a
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute complex commands in Jenkins i prefer the following syntax

```
vagrant ssh -- who -a
```

where everything after the '--' is passed as a command to the VM's shell.

From http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html:

> If a -- (two hyphens) are found on the command line, any arguments after this are passed directly into the ssh executable.